# Using ROS commands over ssh?

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, ssh, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to launch a node using a launch file on a remote computer from a local machine but I am getting the error: "error launching on [192.168.1.7-0, uri http://ai2:37824/]: Name or service not known."  I have the ROS_MASTER_URI set to the local machine (the machine attempting to launch the file).  I also noticed that when I try ssh'ing into the remote computer and running a ROS command on the same line, it does not work.

For example:

```
ssh ai2@192.168.1.7 
rostopic list // works

ssh ai2@192.168.1.7 ls // works

ssh ai2@192.168.1.7 rostopic list // does not work
```

It seems that something about ssh'ing and executing a ROS command on the same line does not work and I think this problem is related to the problem I am having with the launch file.  Has anyone ever dealt with this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229162/using-ros-commands-over-ssh?/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) on 2016-03-15**:
What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to run rostopic list on your own computer after SSHing? Or are you trying to SSH then run rostopic list on the computer you SSHed into?

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-15**:
I am trying to run rostopic list on the same line as ssh.  For whatever reason, if I ssh into the remote and then run rostopic list separately, there are no errors.  But if I ssh and rostopic list on the same line, I get "bash: rostopic: command not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you are attempting to run `ssh ai2@192.168.1.7 rostopic list` you are attempting to run it on a non-interactive shell.

I believe the issue you are having is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works

From the answer there, make sure your `source /path/to/setup.bash` is before the following lines in your .bashrc:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-16**:
Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed.